# Is this GA Ecommerce Tracking Code working?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, enhanced-ecommerce

I donot know much about GA Ecommerce Tracking Code, but work need. I take the follow GA ecommerce tracking code from other way, my problem is I do not sure whether this code is working, I want some professional guys help me to check this, and give me some advice. The code may be a little long, thank you for your kindness.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('set', 'currencyCode', 'USD'); // Set tracker currency to Euros.

ga('ec:addImpression', {            // Provide product details in an 
impressionFieldObject.
'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
'category': 'Apparel/T-Shirts',   // Product category (string).
'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
'variant': 'Black',               // Product variant (string).
'list': 'Search Results',         // Product list (string).
'position': 1,                    // Product position (number).
'dimension1': 'Member'            // Custom dimension (string).
});

ga('ec:addProduct', {
'id': 'P12345',
'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt',
'category': 'Apparel',
'brand': 'Google',
'variant': 'black',
'price': '21.89',
'quantity': 1
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
id: 'T12345',
affiliation: 'Google Store - Online',
revenue: '28.03',
tax: '2.14',
shipping: '4.00',
coupon: 'SUMMER2013'
});

ga('ec:addPromo', {               // Promo details provided in a 
promoFieldObject.
'id': 'PROMO_1234',             // Promotion ID. Required (string).
'name': 'Summer Sale',          // Promotion name (string).
'creative': 'summer_banner2',   // Creative (string).
'position': 'banner_slot1'      // Position  (string).
});

function onProductClick() {
ga('ec:addProduct', {
'id': 'P12345',
'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt',
'category': 'Apparel',
'brand': 'Google',
'variant': 'black',
'position': 1
});

// Send the promo_click action with an event.
ga('ec:setAction', 'promo_click');
ga('send', 'event', 'Internal Promotions', 'click', 'Summer Sale');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You've presented over 100 lines of code and talked about solving a problem, but without saying what the problem is. Does your code work? If so, you'd be better off posting it on CodeReview, although with a clearer statement of what aspect you're considering. If it doesn't work, what happens compared with what you expected?

Comment: Thank you for you advice, I have changed the question, something I just want to tell, but forget whether others can hear me.

Comment: While I have sympathy for your predicament, this still isn't really a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you're not sure whether the code is working or not, I don't think anyone else is going to be in a much better place to determine that. Does it look like it's working as far as you've seen so far? Do you have any *specific* concerns?

Answer (score 0):

The best wait to see if your tracking code is working is to check the Google analytics website.   If you check the real-time api then hits will appear there as soon as they happen.   This way you know if you are getting actual hits.

The more advanced hits you are going to have to wait up to 24 hours before the data is processed and they show in the standard reports.   Only you know your data and only you will know if the data you inserted is the correct data displayed in the Google analytics reports.

**OTT**

If you really want to be sure there are no actual errors in what you are submitting then you can try and duplicate your request using the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en)  which has an option for validating hits [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits)  this should only be needed if for example you are just not seeing any data in your reports after 24 hours.